# svg icon does not stay on the polyline when I zoom out

Tags: google-maps

My svg icon does not remain on the polyline when I zoom in: Can anyone point out the issue. I have been playing with origin and anchor without success.  Thanks!

```
pinMarker:function(color){
    return {
        path:  "M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z",
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 1,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,-5),
        rotation: 0
    };
}



var pinMarker = this.pinMarker(teamColors[i]);
var distanceKm=teamDistance[i]/1312;
var point = this.moveAlongPath(this.routePoints, distanceKm);
this.flagPoints.push(point);
teamMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id:teamName[i],
    position: point,
    map:this.map,
    icon:pinMarker,
    zIndex:(teamName[i] == currentTeamName)? 60000 : 50000
});
```

Comment: Most likely the anchor is wrong.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: In the process of creating a stand alone example I discovered the geodesic attribute on the polyline was not set. Once I set it to true the issue resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: That's why mcves are useful.